# vim: how to trace back all changes done to file during the day

Tags: files, vim, backup, session

Does anybody know how to setup vim (the text editor) in such a way to make it possible to trace back all the changes done to a file within a day? I need it for the cases when I have accidentially modified a subroutine and would like to return it to it's initial state, as it was at the start of the day.

I usually use svn to keep the most recent version of my source code in a global repository. But sometimes I need to return to the state the code was in in between of two svn commits.

**Update:**

To enable *persistent undo* create the undo directory, e.g. `~/.vim/undodir`, and place the [following settings](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19548) into the `.vimrc` file:

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set undolevels=1000
set undoreload=10000
```

Comment: Could you explain what these lines do:
set undolevels=1000
set undoreload=10000

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a large enough value of `'undolevel'`, Vim should be able to undo the whole day's changes. If you quit Vim in between, you also need to enable *persistent undo* by setting the `'undofile'` option.

Vim captures not just a sequential list of commands for undo, but actually a tree of all changes. It also has several commands around undo (cp. `:help undo-branches`); to go back to the state at the beginning of the day,

```
:earlier 12h
```

is a good candidate.

There are also plugins like [Gundo](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) and [undotree.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177), which visualize the undo tree and allow to navigate it.

If navigating the undo tree sounds too cumbersome (e.g. because you make a lot of changes throughout the day), you can also add a lightweight version control system (in addition to Subversion), like my [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828), and explicitly create a backup at certain times.

Answer (score 3):

For several years I've been using a script wrapper around `vi` that saves the files I'm editing. It does this at most once per day so that I don't end up with too many backup files.

This is a simpler version of the script I use; perhaps it's useful for you too. Instead of running `vi`, you would run `vib` (vi with backup):

```
vib() {
    local DATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') FILE BACK
    for FILE in "$@"
    do
        BACK="$FILE.$DATE"
        test ! -f "$BACK" && cp -p "$FILE" "$BACK"
    done
    vi "$@"
    for FILE in "$@"
    do
        BACK="$FILE.$DATE"
        cmp -s "$FILE" "$BACK" && rm -f "$BACK"
    done
}
```

This can either be put into the `.bash_profile` or, with the function declaration removed, put into an executable file such as `/usr/local/bin/vib`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you write `function vib() {...}` or `vib() {...}`? I also changed the `rm` command to `\rm` because of trash-cli things. I also had to add `export -f vib` below the script.

Comment: @Cadoiz the `function` keyword is non-standard so you should aim to avoid using it. If you put this code in a script file in your `$PATH` you can have a new command that doesn't need to worry about aliases for `rm`, etc